# How to customize react date picker header, weekends?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-datepicker

I would like to know how to customize the react datepicker, the main customizations I would like to do are when I click on the header, a grid appears to select the year and month, and if there is a way to disable and paint the weekends with a different color.

Here is my code:

```
function EditDatePicker(props: GridRenderEditCellParams<string>) {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date | null>(new Date());
  const openToDate = new Date('01/01/2022');

  return (
    <DatePicker
      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      dateFormatCalendar={"MMM yyyy"}
      minDate={subMonths(new Date(), 6)}
      maxDate={addMonths(new Date(), 6)}
      showMonthYearDropdown
      openToDate={openToDate}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: try [react-calendar](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-calendar/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I tried to use react-calendar, but my element is inside a DataGrid. Is there a way to open react-calendar by clicking on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can check in the documentation:

> [Custom header](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-custom-header)
>
> [Custom weeks colors](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-custom-calendar-class-name)

This Custom Hook Example worked for me:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import { getMonth, getYear } from "date-fns";
import range from "lodash/range";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";


export default function UseDatepicker(props) {
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
const years = range(1990, getYear(new Date()) + 0, 1);
const months = [
    "Janvier",
    "Février",
    "Mars",
    "Avril",
    "Mai",
    "Juin",
    "Juillet",
    "Août",
    "Septembre",
    "Octobre",
    "Novembre",
    "Décembre",
];

return (
    <DatePicker
        className="custom-input-style"
        renderCustomHeader={({
            date,
            changeYear,
            changeMonth,
            decreaseMonth,
            increaseMonth,
            prevMonthButtonDisabled,
            nextMonthButtonDisabled,
        }) => (
            <div
                style={{
                    margin: 10,
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                }}
            >
                <button
                    onClick={decreaseMonth}
                    disabled={prevMonthButtonDisabled}
                >
                    {"<"}
                </button>
                <select
                    className="custom-select-style"
                    value={getYear(date)}
                    onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
                        changeYear(value)
                    }
                >
                    {years.map((option) => (
                        <option key={option} value={option}>
                            {option}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </select>

                <select
                    className="custom-select-style"
                    value={months[getMonth(date)]}
                    onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
                        changeMonth(months.indexOf(value))
                    }
                >
                    {months.map((option) => (
                        <option key={option} value={option}>
                            {option}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </select>

                <button
                    onClick={increaseMonth}
                    disabled={nextMonthButtonDisabled}
                >
                    {">"}
                </button>
            </div>
        )}
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
    />
);
}
```

Hope this help! :)